Netlify Identity gives error on trying to sign up using netlify cms, even though the UI appears (Jekyll)
So if I accept the invite to sign up to my site (to use admin panel), I get the pop-up but if I try to sign up, it gives me a 404 error.

Same thing happens in the admin page as well.
Site: https://shashiks.netlify.app
Source Code: https://github.com/vishalscodes/sks
I have set the github gateway too.
Any help is appreciated.

probably the url is just wrong?

But I clicked on the log in with github button after accepting the invite. Isn't that the correct way to do this?

@mb21 Assuming it is so, can you tell me what could be the correct URL? Any help is appreciated.

If you haven't setup an authentication provider, you'll get a 404.
https://decapcms.org/docs/github-backend/
You need to prepare an oauth provider to use github as a backend.

I'm sorry, but can you tell me how to do that, I have followed the docs, but can't get anything other than the 404.

Have you done this step? -> https://docs.netlify.com/security/secure-access-to-sites/oauth-provider-tokens/#using-an-authentication-provider If you have already done, it's my misunderstanding.

Yep, that netlify doc did the trick, thanks for the help!
